# GridView - Creating multiple tables on new row commit

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a grid that is bound to a table in EF.  I recently changed the design and I am getting the following exception.

```
Entities in 'CFETSDBContainer.FREQUENCIES' participate in the 'FREQUENCYFreqPool' relationship. 0 related 'FreqPool' were found. 1 'FreqPool' is expected.
```

Why it is doing this is obvious, but I don't know HOW to fix it. When the user enters a new row in the data grid and commits it, it needs to create the new FREQ_POOL and FREQ_TYPE entries as well.

FREQ_POOL and FREQ_TYPE are base classes, and so I need to manually set the types of both and set their properties in the code-behind I believe.

How do I do this? I have only done simple databinding. Here is my code.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="278" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,31,0,0" Name="dgIA" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="520" Loaded="dataGrid1_Loaded" RowEditEnding="dgIA_RowEditEnding" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Name" Header="GACC" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Name}" x:Name="cbGACCS" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ZONE.GACC,Mode=TwoWay}" />            
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Name" Header="Zones" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Name}" x:Name="cbZONES" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ZONE,Mode=TwoWay}" />                
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Frequency" Binding="{Binding Path=Frequency,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Frequency Type" x:Name="cbFT"  SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=FrequencyType,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Owner" x:Name="cbOwner" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Owner,Mode=TwoWay}" />  

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Usage Type" Binding="{Binding Path=UsageType,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comments" Binding="{Binding Path=Comments,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial #" Binding="{Binding Path=Serial,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    private void dgIA_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isManualEditCommit)
        {
            isManualEditCommit = true; 

                DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
                grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            isManualEditCommit = false;
        }      

    }
}
```

[image]